# How to add points to already created polygon using svg.js

Tags: javascript, polygon, svg.js

I've written some code which determines when user clicks on a polygon near to edges. I collect the mouse coordinates and want to add this point to polygon. For this, I'm adding points to `poly.array().value` on proper location. But I'm not able to understand how should it be reflected on the screen.

Sample code

```
poly.on('mousedown', function(event){
    var points = myCanvas.point(event.x, event.y);
    var polyArray = poly.array().value;
    polyArray.splice(i+1, 0, [points] );
});
```

Possible approach that I can think (seems a hack not the proper solution) is to add points to polygon SVG element manually. I was wondering if there is a method in svg.js element to update the element and replot it.

Comment: `I've written some code....` where is your code? Please share the relevant part or possible a runnable snippet.

Comment: @VicJordan Though the question is not about the issue with the code, but I've added that if it can help to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source code of svg.draw.js, and found that there is a method **plot** which can re-plot the polygon with new points `poly.plot(polyArray);`